# Why does Flask g (global) not work with Flask-RESTX?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restx

Adding swagger to my application, I decided to use Flask-RESTX.
I also have a `security_check` that must be executed before each request,

```
@app.before_request
def security_check():
    user_uuid = request.headers.get("UserUuid", None)
    user: = get_user_by_userUuid_service(user_uuid)
    g.user = user
    return user
```

I have `decorators.py` to verify authorized users. I can't use the built-in `login_user()` and don't want to

```
def has_authorize_user(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def decorate(*args, **kwargs):
        if g.user is not None:
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return response
        else:
            return Response("User is unauthorized", status=401)

    return decorate

def transactional(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        with app.app_context():
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)
            
    return wrapped
```

`routes.py`

```
api.add_resource(CloseController, f"/api", methods=['GET', 'POST'], endpoint='close-controller')
```

`controller.py`

```
class CloseController(Resource):
    def get(self):
        response = get_close_service()
        return response
```

`service.py`

```
@transactional
def get_close_service():
    # g.user == None
    ...
```

The problem is that when requesting to `http://127.0.0.1/api`, not possible to get `g.user` inside `CloseController`.

What are the ways to solve this problem and How works global variables in Flask g together with Flask-RESTX? ?

I was looking for a similar `before_request` method in Flask-REST, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: because they run in self contained threads ... and if you are using something like gunicorn it will share threads, but likely not how you are expecting ... so two users may easily get mixed up this way .... basically this is not how you do authentication

Comment: Then how better checking authentication? @JoranBeasley

Comment: you session storage, or tokens, ...for a rest api you typically include an API token in the headers

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't specify 1 more decorator in question. I have  transactional decorator in which I do with app.app_context(), which why the variable g being overwritten, how can I solve this problem because SQLAlchemy requires app.app_context() ?@JoranBeasley

Answer (score 0):

I came to decision that for http requests, `transactional` works without `with app.app_context()`,
instead i did `with Session(engine_)`

For non-http requests, i pass user to function (for example in headers).

You can also use `session['user'] = user` for communication between functions